# How to configure text bold for certain column in react tabulator

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

I am using react-tabulator for my app:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tabulator

I want to format one of the column to have bold text.
I have tried formatter: "bold"

```
columns = () =>{
    return (
      [
        { title: "Title", field: "title1", headerSort: false, width: 180, formatter:"bold",  hozAlign: "right"  },
      ]}
```

I tried add a cssClass to the column

```
columns = () =>{
    return (
      [
        { title: "Title", field: "title1", headerSort: false, width: 180, cssClass: 'data-header,  hozAlign: "right"  },
      ]}
```

with definition of the class in  styles.css
`.data-header {  font-weight: "bold" }`

Nothing works.
Is it possible to also style a particular row in react-tabulator?
Thanks for the help, all the experts out there.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, just for the benefit of others.
I need to configure the styles.css with the following for the cssCass to work:

```
.tabulator .data-header { 
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```